# Does uploading or merging a document into an Azure Search Index update the Data-source when the indexer runs?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am fairly new to Azure Search and I am unsure how to properly update both the index as well as the data-source the index uses. Let's say I am updating a customer index by uploading or merging a document into the index. Is there some behind the scenes work done by the indexer (when it runs) that will then update the data-source to reflect the new updated index, or would I need to use a separate API call to update the data-source separately? I am concerned that when the indexer runs again, it will overwrite any updated documents in the index. I was under the impression that the indexer would only take new data from the data-source and update the index but now I am unsure if it goes both ways. If any further information or explanation is needed I would be happy to supply. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the index will not change anything in your database, no. That does mean that the indexer will proceed normally, and if new or updated documents appear in the data source (according to the way change detection has been configured on your indexer), they will get picked up and indexed (which should hopefully give the same results as your manual push to the index if it comes from the same source document, so shouldn't be an issue). What's difficult to understand in your question is why you are manually pushing to the index at all. Why not let the indexer pick up the data source changes and push to the index?

Comment: Thank you for the timely response. I would be manually adding to the index so that it is available to search on right away instead of adding it to the data-source and then waiting for the indexer to run before it can be searched on. If the indexer will not update the data-source, what would be the "proper" way of updating both knowing that in my ideal situation, the index should be updated manually to allow for instant searching?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Why does it need to go through the indexer if you're going to push it to the index yourself? Especially as you said you didn't want the indexer to overwrite your manually added documents in the index.

Comment: The indexer will periodically run. I want to be sure the changes made by manually pushing to the index won't be deleted.

Comment: Right, but if your indexer definition is consistent with your manual index pushes, why and how does it matter?